# How to find the --configure string once the software has been installed and the source code is still laying around?

Tags: installation, configuration, automation

Here's a typical scenario - you install software from source, spend an hour figuring out the configure options, and finally run:

```
./configure --prefix=/a/b/c --with-X --with-Y=/usr/local/Y/lib \
            --disable-Z --with-extension=foo --build=bar ...
```

A year passes by, a new software version has come out, and you want to upgrade. To do that you need to run configure again on the new source code. However you've forgotten what the configure flags were, but you still do have the old source code and the old build somewhere in your home directory.

How to recover the configure string a year later when you've forgotten what the original configure string was?

Answer (score 2):

Run in the old directory:

```
./config.status --config
```

Or to make things really easy, run in the new directory:

```
./configure `../old-version-directory/config.status --config`
```

Answer (score 0):

In the source code's directory view the `config.log` file.  It will have the `configure` command that was used plus the output of the most recent `configure` that was done.

The log file is helpful when you're building it on another server and want to make sure it configures the same.  Some software will automatically enable or disable certain features when a dependency isn't installed, but still have the `configure` script exit successfully.